# How can I access a variable set in the same function

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

I am trying to create a sortable list and then pass that to my controller in Codeigniter. I can see that the variable gets set, but when I try to access it from the .submit(function) it isn't there.

Here is the code. I am setting postData and trying to access it later.
Thanks for you help:

```
<script>
$(window).load(function() {
var postData = '';
    $( "#sortMe" ).sortable({
        update: function(event, ui) {
            var postData =  $(this).sortable('toArray');
            $( "#sortMe" ).disableSelection();
            //$.post("do_finishcreate", {var: postData}); 
        }
    });

    $( "#draft_order" ).submit(function( event ) {
        var draftData = postData;
        console.log(draftData);
        alert ("test" + draftData);
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is since you have used `var postData` in the update handler, it becomes a local variable and will be accessible only inside the update handler.

One possible solution is to remove the `var` from the update handler so that you can update the closure variable declared in the `window.load` handler.

But I think there is no need to use that too... you can just read the value in the submit handler like

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $("#sortMe").sortable({
        update: function (event, ui) {
            $("#sortMe").disableSelection();
            //$.post("do_finishcreate", {var: postData}); 
        }
    });

    $("#draft_order").submit(function (event) {
        //read in the submit handler, no need to do it in the update hadnler
        var draftData = $('#sortMe').sortable('toArray');
        console.log(draftData);
        alert("test" + draftData);
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are again intialising `var postData` inside `$( "#sortMe" ).sortable` which is making `postData` as local variable instead of global variable,as you are making `postData` as global so don't intialise it again and correct your code as shown below :-

```
$( "#sortMe" ).sortable({
     update: function(event, ui) {
     postData =  $(this).sortable('toArray');  //<----- change here
     $( "#sortMe" ).disableSelection();
    //$.post("do_finishcreate", {var: postData}); 
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me. When I tried the first example I was alerted with an object and not the array. Why is that? I just started to learn jquery and just trying to wrap my head around it.

Comment: @Model359...instead of alerting it.. try console.log() and then check in browser console.. it should be an array in my opinion.

Comment: Yup, it looks like an aray with console.debug

Comment: ["team_31", "team_32", "team_33", "team_41", "team_46", "team_34", "team_35", "team_36", "team_37", "team_38", "team_42", "team_43", "team_44", "team_45", "team_47", "team_48", "team_49", "team_40", "team_39", "team_50", "team_51", "team_52", "team_53", "team_54", "team_55", "team_56", "team_57", "team_58", "team_59", "team_60"]
now I just need to pass this to my controller through a submit post.

Comment: @Model359...i think your this question is solved so plz accept the answer from here and post a new question because i will not be able to answer your question in comments and also if i answer your another question here it will spoil this answer also so plz post a new question and accept a answer from here.. thankss..